# text processing question: remove rows where one column does not contain a particular value

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tab delimited file that looks like this:

```
input_sequence  match_sequence  score   receptor_group  epitope antigen organism    
ASRPPGGVNEQF    ASRPPGGVNEQF    1.00    25735   EPLPQGQLTAY surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]  SARS-CoV2
ASSYSGGYEQY ASSYSGGYEQY 1.00    33843   KTAYSHLSTSK polymerase  Hepatitis B virus (hepatitis B virus (HBV))
ASSYSGGYEQY ASSYSGGYEQY 1.00    131430  KLSYGIATV   orf1ab polyprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]    SARS-CoV2
ASSYSGGYEQY ASSFSGGYEQY 0.97    82603   FTISVTTEIL  surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]  SARS-CoV2
ASSYSGGYEQY ASSYAGGYEQY 0.98    133155  FVCNLLLLFVTVYSHLLLV ORF3a protein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2] SARS-CoV2
ASSLFGSTDTQY    ASSLFGSTDTQY    1.00    92508   FTISVTTEIL  surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]  SARS-CoV2
```

I want to keep 'input_sequence' that only match with 'organism' = SARS-CoV2 and nothing else. So in this example I would keep only line 2 and line 7 and discard lines 3,4,5,6 because here this 'input_sequence' has also a hit with Hepatitis B virus.

In total I have over 20.000 rows in my file.

results required:

```
input_sequence  match_sequence  score   receptor_group  epitope antigen organism    
ASRPPGGVNEQF    ASRPPGGVNEQF    1.00    25735   EPLPQGQLTAY surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]  SARS-CoV2
ASSLFGSTDTQY    ASSLFGSTDTQY    1.00    92508   FTISVTTEIL  surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]  SARS-CoV2
```

Is there a way to quickly do this using awk or bash (without writing a long script)? Any tips are welcome.

I thought to use awk to count the occurences of each value in column 1 and occurences of SARS-COV2 in column 7, and then only keep those that match... but I don't know how to do this. I only got this far (counting the number of occurrences in column one):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ /^/)x++;print x;x=0}' file
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are the fields delimited in your file?

Comment: They are delimited by a tab

Comment: It's hard to tell the difference between tabs and spaces in the post. Can you post it using [table markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)?

Comment: There are only 6 lines (not including the header). How can it print lines 1 and 7?

Comment: Done @Barmar, it are indeed 6 lines

Comment: Now I'm more confused. The first line in the desired result has `organism=[Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]` not `organism=SARS-Cov2`.

Comment: Line 3 has `SARS-CoV2`, why isn't it in the expeted result?

Comment: The table layout is doing something strange, in one of the comments below you are right: I think he actually wants some kind of join on the input_sequence column. Line 2 doesn't have SARS-CoV2, so none of the rows with the same input_sequence= ASSYSGGYEQY  should be printed. --> this is exactly what i want but don't know how to do, perhaps it would be easier in sql

Comment: Dont post a "table layout" or any other graphical representation of your data, simply post your actual textual data.

Comment: Somebody else asked me to post it like this, I will edit it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
awk '
    NR==1                              # Print first line (header)
    $NF != "SARS-CoV2" { bad[$1] }     # Collect primary keys of "bad"  records based on content in last field
    $NF == "SARS-CoV2" { good[$1]=$0 } # Collect primary keys of "good" records with opposite check
    END {
        for(v in bad) delete good[v]   # Remove primary keys from "good" records that also appear in "bad" records
        for(v in good) print good[v]   # Print the "good" rows
    }
' file
```

Passing the file once, this could potentially be a solution. This will delete any duplicate entries.

Comment: This works perfectly THANKS - and this code also discards the duplicates. The answer of @anubhava also works but keeps duplicate lines.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider this awk that joins same file on 1st column:

```sh
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {$NF != "SARS-CoV2" && bad[$1]; next}
FNR == 1 || !($1 in bad)' file{,} | column -s $'\t' -t

input_sequence  match_sequence  score  receptor_group  epitope      antigen                                                                          organism
ASRPPGGVNEQF    ASRPPGGVNEQF    1.00   25735           EPLPQGQLTAY  Trans-activator protein BZLF1 [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]  SARS-CoV2
ASSLFGSTDTQY    ASSLFGSTDTQY    1.00   92508           FTISVTTEIL   surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]           SARS-CoV2
```

PS: `column -s $'\t' -t` has been used for tabular display only. You can remove it.

---

If you want to remove dues based on 1st column then use:

```sh
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {$NF != "SARS-CoV2" && bad[$1]; next}
FNR == 1 || (!($1 in bad) && !seen[$1]++)' file{,}
```

Comment: @XelaVi I have updated answer to remove dupes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two passes over the input.

The first pass makes an array whose keys are the input sequences that have an organism other than `SARS-CoV2`. The second pass checks if the current input sequence is in that array. If not, it prints the line.

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {if ($7 != "SARS-CoV2") {a[$0]=1}; next}
            !a[$0]' file file
```